# Insert into where date column value doesn't already exist

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the below query that I want to create a table `new_table` and then each day `INSERT INTO new_table` that checks if the date exists in date_final, if it doesn't load those rows.

The first COALESCE line has 3 values (`p_date, c_date, t_date`), each was created from a CTE from different tables that have a date loaded daily.

```
INSERT INTO my_table(
    SELECT 
        COALESCE (p_date, c_date, t_date) AS date_final,
        COALESCE (p_name,cl_name,c_name) AS brand
    FROM p  
    FULL JOIN clicks ON cli.c_date = PAGES.p_date
    FULL JOIN comm_agg ON comm_agg.t_date = p.p_date 
    LEFT JOIN ga ON ga.date_f = p.p_date 
)
where date_final dates do not already exist in the new_table
```

meaning in the new_table if date_final already has the dates 2/12, 2/14 then I want to make sure when doing the insert I want to make sure I don't re-load those dates

Comment: are you finding like where date_final is null

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin I'm trying to find where date_final date does not already appear in the existing new_table. So if the existing new_table has the dates 2/12, 2/13 then the insert into should only insert 2/14, 2/15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO my_table
SELECT 
    COALESCE (p_date, c_date, t_date) AS date_final,
    COALESCE (p_name,cl_name,c_name) AS brand
FROM p  
    FULL JOIN clicks ON cli.c_date = PAGES.p_date
    FULL JOIN comm_agg ON comm_agg.t_date = p.p_date 
    LEFT JOIN ga ON ga.date_f = p.p_date 
where COALESCE (p_date, c_date, t_date) is null
```